# Why would my iPhone 6 be stuck in a dead battery boot loop?

Tags: startup, iphone

Okay, so I have a problem. My iPhone 6 died (it runs a non-jailbroken version of iOS, I used it as a test device for development applications, but I didn't do anything crazy with the firmware of the phone). I plugged the phone in and got an Apple logo, and then it died again. It's on a loop.

What it looks like is happening is, when the phone is charging, it's above 5% battery, so it turns on. However, for some odd reason, the phone doesn't turn on all the way when it boots up; instead, it just shuts off again.

Then the phone goes back to "charging from dead" again. It's in an infinite loop.

Why would this suddenly happen? It's an unjailbroken iPhone 6 running the latest iOS (non-beta, iOS 8.4). How would I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like a problem for the Apple Store to me, I have an old android tablet that does similar antics (too expensive to try to fix).

Comment: @ScottPorter I'm trying to avoid paying someone to fix this. I feel like there might be a solution to this that I can do without paying somebody.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In such cases I, myself, do a boot into DFU mode which actually uses way less energy mainly because the display stays off. 
Then I wait for about a half an hour and then I reboot the iDevice in order to have it properly booted.

P.S. Follow this procedure in order to enter an iDevice into DFU mode:

1. Make sure your iDevice is plugged into a power source via it's USB cable;
2. Hold down both Home and Power buttons on the iDevice for about 10 seconds until the screen goes off;
3. Keep holding the Home button and release the Power button;
4. Open  iTunes to check if the iDevice is connected. A message saying that an iDevice in a Recovery mode is connected should show up.

Answer (score 3):

Its a software bug it should not boot until the battery is strong enough. Instead it boots to soon and the screen stays on keeping the battery from charging.

Fix one if it does come up to the unlock screen quickly unlock it and then off the screen it will then stop rebooting and charge up.

Fix 2 if you cant get it unlocked hold down the home screen while rebooting and leave it on the screen that says to connect to itunes. Let it charge on this screen with a original charger and cord.

Remember its the screen being on thats stopping it from charging.

This is a defect in the current OS its not reading you battery voltage and rebooting to soon. Ours only started doing this after the latest OS update.

Comment: Right; the screen was on full brightness during boot. See [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199374/132258).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get out of the loop by following the above steps..

1. Plug in iPhone into USB on PC
2. Hold the home and power button together until screen is black. Release the power button and only hold the home button until iTune symbol appears.
3. Now, unplug the iPhone and plug it into the wall charger, NOT the USB charger on PC.  This action allowed the phone to keep charging without entering the boot loop
4. If the Apple logo reappears, then try step 2 again.
5. The phone will clear itself and power again with the login screen.
6. It worked for me in less than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

The phone is stuck in infinite loop because the battery is discharged just enough to boot the phone up after a short charge time; but as soon as the phone goes into the boot loop, the white boot screen discharges the battery below booting threshold and the phone shuts down again and this loop keeps going forever.

None of the above worked for me, but this solution worked:

1. plug in iphone into USB on PC
2. hold the home and power button together for a long time - approximately 20 seconds. It is really long time, keep holding.
3. the phone screen should display the cord and the word itunes
4. now unplug iphone and plug it into the wall charger, NOT the USB charger on PC
5. this action allowed the phone to keep charging without entering the boot loop
6. I charged all night, you can probably just stop after 1/2 hour

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came across this same exact problem on my jailbroken iphone 6. I tried a lot of different methods, and even resorted to heating the back of my phone with a blow dryer because a video told me to. After I thought all hope was lost, I tried one last thing, not expecting it to work.

I held the power on button while inserting the power cable in order to boot my phone into recovery mode. It's important to do this with a wall charger, and not with your computer. Then, I just left it overnight on the recovery screen.

When I came back in the morning, it was still on the recovery screen, so I did a force shutdown by holding the power and home buttons. When I tried to boot it up after, it worked!

You just have to keep it charging in recovery mode long enough so that the phone has time to charge itself to a point where it can boot up on its own. Tell me if this also works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try another charger.  They go up to 3A or even 4A and can can supply the phone with enough power to keep the screen on and charge the device simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. Turns out, the phone was on 4.999% when it was starting. When it hit 5.000%, it started up. Because starting up used so much energy, it used more than the cord could provide, causing it to fall back below 5.000%.

Comment: That is not a proper fix. It is not explained how you fixed it. See my previous answer with an explanation.